# VisualStudioSetting command-line property doesn't seem to be working

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I was testing command-line build overrides and noticed that the `VisualStudioSetting` property doesn't appear to be working. I deliberately set a bad value and it build as normal:

```
msbuild MyTestSolution.sln  /p:platform="Win32" /p:configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="19.2"
```

I was expecting to get an error telling me this version of Visual Studio is not available, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Msbuild will ignore the wrong property when build. You can create a error task for it:

```xml
<Target Name="ValidateCommandLine">
    <Error
        Text=" The version of visual studio should be 16.9 or later."
        Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' <= '16.9.0'" />
</Target>
```

Comment: But I'm running from command-line and I see this even if I pass valid VS versions, it just seems to ignore it.